# Problem adding a new node to a SQL Server 2012 Failover Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, failover

- I tried to add a new node to SQL Server (2012 Standard) Failover, that is already installed on another node in Windows2012 Failover Cluster
- I have an issue with non editable field wiht input for SQL Server Agents Account Name
- there could be the same AD name as for SQL Server Database Engine (e.i.)
- my account access haven't AD admin privileges
- access, account and setting for SQL Server Agent on parent node are accesible and settable

[image]

Comment: Go into the active node of the failover cluster and verify that SQL Server Agent is actually a cluster resource of your FCI cluster resource group.  You can do this with PowerShell as well: `Get-ClusterGroup -Name "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" | Get-ClusterResource` (change the name to whatever your cluster resource group name is for your FCI).  You may need to import the failover clusters module depending on what version of PowerShell you are on (`Import-Module -Name failoverclusters`).

Comment: If SQL Server Agent isn't part of the cluster resource group, and if it's not a resource type in the cluster then that can cause the problem you are seeing.  If that is the case, in your situation, then I can show you how to fix that.

Comment: @Thomas Stringer to 2. comment I tried to change account for this component from built_in default account and ended with AD admin access, nothing changed when I tried to add a new node to a SQL ..., looks like as isn't clustered, but no idea why, because all shared features I redirected to clustered disk in initial instalation processes

Comment: You could have had some issues during the install of the FCI that caused SQL Server Agent to not be a cluster resource and a resource type.  So is that what you're seeing?  No SQL Server Agent in the cluster resource group, and no SQL Server Agent cluster resource type?

Comment: aaach  I see, good point, there were problem to start automatically during restart (3times) after (bunch of) updates, I alive SQL Server Agent from services - start

Comment: So can you confirm my last comment?  No SQL Server Agent resource in the FCI resource group, and no SQL Server Agent resource type in the cluster?

Comment: @Thomas Stringer for both questions is answer yes, both aren't presented, but my idea would be to create a new cluster, because my 1st attempt (used built_in accesses) ended with success, I'm leaning and to trying whatever is possible, please to see my  [another question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44865/windows-server-failover-cluster)

Comment: Answer posted below, let me know if that works for you.  You shouldn't have to create a new cluster to get this one up and running.

Comment: If anyone is interested in a complete walk-through of the solution for SQL 2008 R2, see this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2592/fix-sql-server-agent-on-windows-failover-cluster/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments in your question, what you need to do is two-fold:

1. Add SQL Server Agent as a cluster resource type
2. Add the SQL Server Agent cluster resource to the failover cluster resource group

For the first step, one way to do this is through PowerShell (utilizing the FailoverClusters module):

```
Import-Module -Name FailoverClusters

$ClusterName = "YourClusterName"
$FciClusterGroupName = "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" # may need to modify to reflect your environment

# check to see if you have the SQL Server Agent cluster resource type
Get-Cluster -Name $ClusterName |
    Get-ClusterResourceType |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "SQL Server Agent"}

# if not, add it
Add-ClusterResourceType -Name "SQL Server Agent" -Dll "sqagtres.dll"
```

Execute each of those blocks of code separately instead of just all at once.  You'll be able to confirm whether or not that cluster resource type exists before just blindly attempting to add it.

Then for the second step, here's what you need to do to add the SQL Server Agent as a resource in your failover cluster resource group:

1. Right-Click on your FCI resource group within the failover cluster manager
2. Select "Add a resource" and select the SQL Server Agent resource type
3. Rename the new cluster resource to "SQL Server Agent"
4. Go into the new SQL Server Agent resource properties and set the virtual network name and instance name properties
5. On the dependency tab, set SQL Server as its dependency resource

You may need to go into the registry at the following location and ensure those keys (one will contain the string "AGENT", another "SQL_ENGINE") are set to 1 (this is where it is recorded on what was installed correctly.  1 denotes correct installation):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\YOURINSTANCE\ConfigurationState
```

That *should* get you to a place where you can now install an additional node and have the SQL Server Agent service account appear.  Of course, prior to starting ensure that you have a back out here (especially with the registry editing).

Comment: @mKorbel No problem, glad to help.  Did it work?

Comment: again thanks, very similair steps :-) .......

Comment: real issue was access to create a new Objects in AD (must be manually added) for Failover instance