# SQL Server 2012 Failover Cluster and attached SAN

Tags: sql-server-2012, failover, windows-server

I have three servers in a Windows Server failover cluster.  SQL Server 2012 Failover Cluster is installed on all nodes. I have an issue with shared disks attached from SAN.

overview with the same configurations for all

- DNS are SQL1, SQL2, SQL3
- RAID1 + 5 SAS, 50Gb from SAN for Windows failover, 1TB for SQL failover
- Windows Server failover cluster was initialized from SQL1
- all installations before Windows Server failover cluster was created were initialized from SQL1
- I shared SQL2 -> SQL1

my questions are:

1. All shared disks (SAN 50GB + 1TB) are added to Windows Server failover cluster, but only from SQL1 is possible to leave available storage for SQL Server 2012 Failover Cluster. I'm not able to set available disk on SQL2 / SQL3 node, they can be only members of clustered storage or in offline mode. Is this possible? If yes, then how?
2. (Windows OS specific question) built_in SAS HDDs in RAID1 + 5 isn't possible to add to the pool in Windows Server failover cluster (members are empty) but is possible to create a pool for each of noded in Server view, e.g. then to create iSCSI. Why those two options seems like as not doing the same things; specific server can see available HDD for pool, from Windows failover is/are member empty.
3. Is it possible to migrate with installated SQL Server 2012 Failover Cluster and their files from one storage to another, for example when I attach a new SAN to Windows Server failover cluster?
4. Then is possible to install Windows Server failover cluster only from SQL1? On SQL2 / SQL3 node installations ended with no available storage.

Comment: Did you verify that each node can take ownership of all the necessary resources upon failover? This testing should be done before SQL Server is ever installed. I'm kind of shocked that SQL Server installed successfully on all 3 nodes given the issues you're having.

Comment: @Jon Seigel i had an issue with [SQL Server Agent](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45281/problem-adding-a-new-node-to-a-sql-server-2012-failover-cluster)